# Creating map projection for net of geodesic dome?

Tags: maps, stars

I am working on a project that involves mapping the night sky's northern hemisphere onto the exterior surface of a small (16 cm radius) geodesic dome. The problem is, I don't know what map projection to convert to, or whether I need to create one. If so, I don't really know how.

I'm starting from a high-resolution image of the full night sky in an equirectangular projection in celestial coordinates.

[image: One of the equirectangular images I would like to project onto the geodesic net]

I would like to map that onto the **net** of a geodesic dome, [image: geodesic dome net] so that I can construct the dome with accurate star coordinates. I would like to use a computer program to convert the northern hemisphere of my equirectangular star map into the desired projection, if possible.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source data along with the projection information?

Comment: @RoperMaps Done!

Comment: I don't know of anything that will do it 'out the box' so to speak. However I would start by looking at the D3 geo-projections library. Specifically: https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection#polyhedral-projections . I would probably start out by duplicating your net so you have a 'sphere' and then projecting the whole map on that and then tweaking it till the N Hemisphere is in the right place. This might be quite an undertaking though!